# how can I record Service Stack services stats

Tags: web-services, statistics, servicestack

Is there a plugin for Service Stack that allow me to track services stats, like number of calls, response times, etc ?

We have a lot of services running but we want to start collecting stats for them. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a plugin available to do aggregate request metrics like this that's built into ServiceStack specifically, the closest thing would be the [Request Logger Plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger) which exposes a simple service that logs all requests and lets you query and introspect past requests.

You could provide a similar service to Request Logger where you could implement your own `IRequestLogger` like [InMemoryRollingRequestLogger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Providers/InMemoryRollingRequestLogger.cs) which aggregates and persists the information you want.

Another strategy would be instead of building metrics inside and specific to each Web Framework, to instead aggregate logs using a generic HTTP proxy like HAProxy, Nginx or IIS and to instead run analytic's over the HTTP Proxy logs - this is the approach that companies like StackOverflow does.